# How to get following data from API?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I want to get word, string1, and string2.
Sorry for my bad english and thanks for answering.

This my code:

```
Item item = new Item(jsonObject.getString("word"), 
                     jsonObject.getString("string1"), jsonObject.getString("string2"));
```

And this is the data from API:

```
[{"word":"apple","definitions":[{"string1":"this is string 1",
                                 "string2":"this is string 2""}]}]
```

Comment: `definitions` is an array

Comment: Check this answer for reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463691/android-kotlin-volley-how-to-get-value-from-jsonarray/68463794#68463794

Comment: Shouldn't it be `jsonObject.getJsonArray("definitions").get(0).getString("string1")`  ?

Comment: First access the "word" and then go for "definitions". From definitions, you can dive inside for string1 & string2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your JSON as:

```
[
   {
      "word":"apple",
      "definitions":[
         {
            "string1":"this is string 1",
            "string2":"this is string 2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

From the question it looks like you are not much familiar with JSON, [learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

But for now you have a `JSON Array`, that contains `JSON Object`. Which again has `JSON Array` that has `JSON Object`.

So to answer you question you should be accessing the contents like below:

Note that this code might have some errors because it's not tested. It's your responsibility to modify it accordingly.

**Step 1**:

Get the `JSON Object` from the `JSON Array`. You have some code provided so I'm going to make some assumptions.

```
Item item = new Item(jsonObject.getString("word"), 
                     jsonObject.getString("string1"), jsonObject.getString("string2"));
```

`jsonObject` already has the object from outer array. If this is the case move onto the **Step 2**. Else continue reading this.

```
String json = "your json here"; // paste your provided json here
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

// get the object at index 0
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

// get the "word" value here
String word = jsonObject.getString("word");
```

**Step 2**:

Now we have extracted the `value` of key `word`. Let us extract the `definitions`. Continued from previous example.

```
// getting the json array for definition
JSONArray definitions = jsonObject.getJSONArray("definitions");

// get the object at index 1
// use loop if you want to get multiple values from this array
JSONObject first = definitions.getJSONObject(0);

// finally get your string values
String string1 = first.getString("string1");
String string2 = first.getString("string2");
```

**Complete Code**:

```
String json = "your json here"; // paste your provided json here
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

// get the object at index 0
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

// get the "word" value here
String word = jsonObject.getString("word");

// getting the json array for definition
JSONArray definitions = jsonObject.getJSONArray("definitions");

// get the object at index 1
// use loop if you want to get multiple values from this array
JSONObject first = definitions.getJSONObject(0);

// finally get your string values
String string1 = first.getString("string1");
String string2 = first.getString("string2");
```

And that is it you have to understand `JSON Array` and `JSON Object` before you can understand why and how.

Answer (score 0):

if data is object, you can try

```
var a = [{"word":"apple","definitions":[{"string1":"this is string 1","string2":"this is string 2"}]}]

var string1 = a[0]['definitions'][0]["string1"];
console.log('string 1 =>', string1);
var string2 = a[0]['definitions'][0]["string2"];
console.log('string 1 =>', string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to look at the server response it's cool that you can generate models using [jsonschema2pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). So you can never go wrong.

Just copy your answer there and you will see how simple everything is.
Since then when I tried this tool, I no longer manually perform such conversions.

How do you get a response from the server? Many people use the Retrofit library for this, there you will specify a converter (for example GSON) that converts the answer to your objects created using the jsonschema2pojo.

Good luck!